# What is the use of original-package in manifest

Tags: android, attributes, android-manifest, manifest

Anybody knows what is the exact use of original-package in manifest?

I just got the below comment from [manifest attr](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs_manifest.xml#L1150) link. But don't know how to use, when to use exactly?

> Private tag to declare the original package name that this package is
>        based on.  Only used for packages installed in the system image.  If
>        given, and different than the actual package name, and the given
>        original package was previously installed on the device but the new
>        one was not, then the data for the old one will be renamed to be
>        for the new package.

If anybody knows, please explain it in detail?

Comment: Look for the .project file.  Makes sure your package is named the same there as in your Manifest.

Comment: The quote you've provided makes it pretty clear when and why the attribute is used - what is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell this is attribute is private one and applicable for system packages. i.e if system packages wanted to change package name for some reason as part of Maintenance release this is way to go.

More details:

```
< original-package /> // original-package Should notify PackageManager to do the replacement
```

Per Packageparser.java

```
if (tagName.equals("original-package")) {
            sa = res.obtainAttributes(attrs,
com.android.internal.R.styleable.AndroidManifestOriginalPackage);
String orig =sa.getNonConfigurationString(                             
com.android.internal.R.styleable.AndroidManifestOriginalPackage_name, 0);
if (!pkg.packageName.equals(orig)) {
   if (pkg.mOriginalPackages == null) {
               pkg.mOriginalPackages = new ArrayList<String>();
               pkg.mRealPackage = pkg.packageName;
             }
        pkg.mOriginalPackages.add(orig);
      }
    sa.recycle();
    XmlUtils.skipCurrentTag(parser);
}
```

Private tag to declare the original package name that this package is
based on.  Only used for packages installed in the system image.  If
given, and different than the actual package name, and the given
original package was previously installed on the device but the new
one was not, then the data for the old one will be renamed to be
for the new package. #AndroidManifest manifest tag.

```
<declare-styleable name="AndroidManifestOriginalPackage"parent="AndroidManifest">
<attr name="name" />
</declare-styleable>`
```

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> Private tag to declare the original package name that this package
>   is
>       based on.  Only used for packages installed in the system image.  If
>        given, and different than the actual package name, and the given
>        original package was previously installed on the device but the new
>        one was not, then the data for the old one will be renamed to be
>        for the new package.

```
Eg:

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.deskclock"
    android:versionCode="301" android:versionName="3.0.0">

       <original-package android:name="com.android.alarmclock" />
       <original-package android:name="com.android.deskclock" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it's the ID of your app, and no other app can have the same package name. It should be unique per app. It is mostly used at install time to detect if its the same app, and also for uploading it to Google Play.